# sqlcmd: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have the privilege to connect to db on test2, but if I remote desktop on another host using the same account, and run the following command there

> SQLCMD -E -S test2 -d test -i Silo.sql
>   -b -v
>
> (1 rows affected) 
>   Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server test\colo, Line 1
>   Login failed for user **'NT
>   AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'**.

Why this happen, and what's the workaround?

And strangely, it complains the user is  'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON', but in reality, I used my own account

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error if you have asked for

1. Connect to remote server
2. The local server is in a domain
3. The remote server is not in a domain

The connection will not be made using your domain login (which is unknown on the target, but will instead use ANONYMOUS)

- Looking at your error

> (1 rows affected)  Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, **`Server
>   test\colo`**, Line 1 Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS
>   LOGON'.

It looks instead like part of your script is accessing linked server object from **test** through to **test\colo**, and you have not set up linked server logins correctly.  If **test** and **test\colo** are not on the same domain, then you will need to set up linked server login mapping using [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)

Comment: I am using vpn, so local server is not in domain, but the remote desktop connection is in a domain, and the target db server is also in a domain, so do you think it is the root cause, and what's the workaround

Comment: You have connected to `test2`, but it is accessing `test\colo`. What is the relationship between the two?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known <strike>bug</strike> issue with SQL Server 2005 and later. See SQL Server Products blog

> ["SQL Linked Server Query failed with “Login failed for user …”"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/08/10/694657.aspx)

There is no real fix for it (aside from completely reconfiguring your domain and all servers).

The real fix is to not use **Windows** authentication, and manually enter **SQL Server** credentials in the linked server configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Login SQLCMD and assign sysamdin run following command.

EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
go