# Execute stored procedure, but access denied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to execute a stored procedure. But I this error below, at every stance of execution:

> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 3 Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Thank you.

This is what I try to execute:

```
USE [Artikelen]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[BerekenSKU]
        @loc = N'AM',
        @lev = N'3436',
        @reset = true

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I am using Microsoft SQL 2014

Comment: Looks like you're not authorized to execute the procedure.

Comment: is this in link server?

Comment: Understand. But how to authorize then? Thank you

Comment: you can trying posting the code you used in trying to execute this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Error shows that there is credential issue. Please check this link.

> This message indicates that you are attempting to access the linked
>   server by using Windows NT authentication to impersonate the client
>   connecting. Refer [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238477)
>
> Look at the stored procedure in question. The login is failing at the
>   linked server because whoever is calling it doesn't have mapped
>   credentials set up.

Refer this links:

[sqlcmd: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841845/sqlcmd-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon)

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic548200-146-1.aspx

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1523177-1550-1.aspx

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic246883-110-1.aspx

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic246883-110-1.aspx